# pfSense - NAT not working

Tags: nat, pfsense

I have a pfSense on Proxmox VM. I have two IP addreses configured:

```
WAN: xx.xx.88.24 -> public IP accesible from internet 
LAN: 192.168.1.100 -> corporate intranet
```

I want to access an internal server from WAN. For example, I have a server with 192.168.1.110 IP with a HTTPD server running on default 80 port.

Then, I have created a NAT rule in pfSense:

```
Interface  Protocol  Dest. Address   Dest. Ports  NAT IP         NAT PORTS
WAN        TCP/UDP   xx.xx.88.24     80(HTTP)     192.168.1.110  80(HTTP)
```

With the firewall rule created in the NAT configuration. When trying to test this configuration, I recieve a timeout from the browser. In the **Diagnosticts -> States** I only see this entries:

```
Interface   Protocol   Source -> Destination                           State 
WAN         tcp        (my PC IP) -> 192.168.1.110:80(xx.xx.88.24:80)  CLOSED:SYN_SENT 
LAN         tcp        (my PC IP) -> 192.168.1.110:80               CLOSED:SYN_SENT
```

Any idea? HTTP service is up and runnning in internal server, so internal rule in the server firewall added to accept http service request.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

check your default gateway, this is wrong or not set in your backend server.

> https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Port_Forward_Troubleshooting